# What is the borrow parameter in Theano

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning

I see this following line of code:

```
n_train_batches = train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0] / batch_size
```

In the above line, what is the borrow parameter exactly? What is the advantage of adding that there? FYI, train_set_x is basically a matrix that was generated using the theano.shared method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This part of the documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/aliasing.html#borrowing-when-creating-shared-variables) seems relevant:

> By default (`s_default`) and when explicitly setting `borrow=False`, the shared variable we construct gets a *deep* copy of np_array. So changes we subsequently make to `np_array` have no effect on our shared variable.

Setting it to `True` can then be assumed to make a shallow copy, effectively letting you "borrow" access to the memory.

Comment: Nice and succinct, I had a whole paragraph laid out attempting to explain it that was much more confusing than this, +1